# Queries in Google App Engine using JDOQL

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, persistence, jdo, gql

I have problems using an Object-Orient database instead of traditional relational ones.
I use JDO for Persistance and Google App Engine as the hosting platform.
How can i correctly model my classes in order to support relationships.
In SQL i could make a Join query, but it is not supported at Google's BigTable database.

For example is this approach correct?

```
Class Parent 
{   
    @Persistent(mappedBy="parent")
    List<Child> children;
}

Class Child
{
   @Persistent
   Parent parent;
}
```

What should be the JDOQL query to obtain all the Child objects of a Parent?
I would be very grateful to have some advice. Thank you.

Comment: Please also check this link http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries.html#Introducing_Queries

Comment: what does an ODBMS have to do with bigtable? you use one or the other

Answer (score 0):

GAE support merge-join. You can watch Brett Slatkin's IO 2009 talk "Building Scalable, Complex Apps on App Engine"

http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/BuildingScalableComplexApps.html